# Distribution of Eigenvectors of Random Covariance Matrix

Tags: probability, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices

Let $Q$ be a random symmetric positive definite matrix with a Matrix normal distribution.  Then what can I conclude about the distribution of the eigenvectors of $Q$?

Comment: Is $Q$ real?...

Comment: Yes all real entries.